# What happened to my desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnome, linux-mint, desktop

I have Linux Mint 12 Gnome desktop, everything was normal yesterday. I shut my PC down yesterday and went to sleep, I turned it on today, and see what happened

[image]

You see how everything is messed up? The desktop normally should look like [this](http://www.linuxmint.com/pictures/screenshots/lisa/lisa_light.png). I tried to switch between the Gnome classic and the Gnome classic (no effects), but it make no difference, there are the only themes that i have. When I press restart, it logs me out, it does not restart. I shut it down and turned it on again but there's no difference.

**EDIT**

I have been told that this is Gnome Fallback mode, which is forced on you when your graphics card driver doesn't have the needed 3D acceleration support. This happens mostly with discrete graphics cards with proprietary drivers.

the output of `inxi -Gxc 0` is

```
Graphics: Card: nVidia G86 [GeForce 8500 GT] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org 1.10.4 drivers nouveau unloaded: fbdev,vesa Resolution 1024x768@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer Gallium 0.4 on NV86 GLX Version 2.1 Mesa 7.11 Direct Rendering Yes
```

**Update**

i updated nvidia, now the output is this

```
Graphics: Card: nVidia G86 [GeForce 8500 GT] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org 1.10.4 drivers nvidia unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau Resolution 1024x768@50.0hz 
GLX Renderer GeForce 8500 GT/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version 3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.33 Direct Rendering Yes
```

the error is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your file system is not clean, you should boot in single user mode and check your file system.
Restart your system, at grub menu, chose a line looks like this

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic-paeroot=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx ro vga=794 quiet
```

Press `e` to edit line, edit it to looks like this line:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic-paeroot=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx init=/bin/bash rw
```

Press `b` or hit `enter` to boot in this mode, now you will boot with root permission with out typing  your password, at the shell prompt:

```
fsck -y
```

After fsck finishing checking your file system, restart your system with `reboot`, the system will boot normally with out changing back your modification. I had an issues like this before and checking file system fix it to me.

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, i have been told the cause of the problem on linux mint forum, not the solution :)

Comment: the error is not fixed, i want to try your method sir, I don't see this line `linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-28-generic-paeroot=UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx ro vga=794 quiet` and how to unmount the os in order to do `fsck` i have the linux mint 12 cd

Comment: issue fixed, it was a gnome issue, i installed [cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) and it's better than gnome :)